# Why do we need HTTP instead of SSH?

Tags: http, ssh

Why is there a SMTP/HTTP Protocol? I mean, why can't we use (or extend) the existing SSH protocol? Wouldn't using SSH also eliminate the need for a paid key?

Or, perhaps another why to frame this question is why do we need yet another encryption scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different protocols for different purposes. What I'm hearing here really is 'why do we need to pay for an SSL certificate in HTTPS but not SSH'.

The reason for this is as follows:

When you first connect to a SSH server, you as the person logging in are asked to validate the public key. Do you read it and recognize the code before you accept it?

Imagine if this were needed the first time you connect to *any* HTTPS server. We can't ask users to validate every public key manually. How would they recognize what a public key is the correct one?

We solve this by relying on *other authorities* to validate the keys. These authorities don't just sell SSL certificate, their product really is validating that the person owning the domain is the one encrypting it.

So you can totally generate your own self-signed SSL certificates, but browsers won't recognize these by default. Browsers and operating system have a database of certificates they trust.

Anyway, these days you no longer need to pay for a certificate. LetsEncrypt gives them away for free.